# Not able to publish Hybris Promotion

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

I have created a promotion in hybris 1808 but when I am trying to publish the promotion it's Failing. The same promotion is working in 1808 Vanilla Hybris

I have added following properties in localextension.xml and tried but still facing the same issue

1. promotionenginesamplesaddon
2. promotionengineatddtests

I expected the promotion status to Publish but it's failing while publishing with following error logs :

```
19.04.23 17:54:40:527   INFO    *************************************
19.04.23 17:54:40:535   INFO    Starting RuleEngineCompilePublishJob
19.04.23 17:54:40:535   INFO    *************************************
19.04.23 17:54:44:903   ERROR   The rule compilation finished with errors
19.04.23 17:54:44:910   ERROR   Exception caught - de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException: [de.hybris.platform.droolsruleengineservices.interceptors.DroolsRuleValidateInterceptor@3d9f547f]:rule(code:testPromotion) The drl content does not contain the matching rule declaration with the value of your hybris rule's uuid attribute. Please adjust the uuid of your hybris rule and/or add: rule "2e0e0ac2-7475-44c1-9114-07a0d7174534" (i.e. putting the rule uuid in double-quotes) in your drl content.
19.04.23 17:54:44:915   INFO    *************************************
19.04.23 17:54:44:915   INFO    RuleEngineCompilePublishJob finished with errors
19.04.23 17:54:44:915   INFO    *************************************
```

Comment: Please let me know if any other information is needed

Answer (score 1):

Which verion of hybris are you using?

Because I faced this while upgrading from 6.3 to 6.7 while publishing the promotion.

I had overridden the method in my custom class in 6.3 which looks has follows:

```
@Override
    protected String generateRuleContentRule(final DroolsRuleGeneratorContext context, final String actions, final String metadata)
    {
        final AbstractRuleModel rule = context.getRuleCompilerContext().getRule();
        final Map variables = context.getVariables();
        final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(4096);
        buffer.append("rule \"").append(rule.getUuid()).append("\"\n");
        buffer.append("@ruleCode(\"").append(rule.getCode()).append("\")\n");
        buffer.append(metadata);
        buffer.append("dialect \"mvel\" \n");
        buffer.append("salience ").append(rule.getPriority()).append('\n');
```

...

This overridden method from the class DefaultDroolsRuleTargetCodeGenerator had to be changed to include droolRule uuid rather than rule uuid which is the change incorporated in OOTB DefaultDroolsRuleTargetCodeGenerator class in 6.7

```
     protected String generateRuleContentRule(DroolsRuleGeneratorContext context, String actions, String metadata) {
    AbstractRuleModel rule = context.getRuleCompilerContext().getRule();
    DroolsRuleModel droolsRule = context.getDroolsRule();
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(4096);
    buffer.append("rule \"").append(droolsRule.getUuid()).append("\"\n");
    buffer.append("@ruleCode(\"").append(rule.getCode()).append("\")\n");
    buffer.append("@moduleName(\"").append(context.getRuleCompilerContext().getModuleName()).append("\")\n");
    buffer.append(metadata);
    buffer.append("dialect \"mvel\" \n");
```

This resolved the error above.

Hope this helps.
Happy Coding.